# Finding erlang binary references

Tags: reference, erlang, binary-data, trace

Erlang reference counts large binaries and created sub binaries which prevent the referenced binary from being deallocated during garbage collection.

I can see the allocated binary amount in the observer or in erlang:memory()

The problem is that tracking down where the larger binary is coming from is proving challenging. Is there any specific technique or tool that can be used to find the referenced data for inspection, or the function that originally created the reference via tracing?

Comment: I know this is a really old question, but were you able to solve this? I looked into the Recon library, but I couldn't really find a way to work out where the large binaries come from. I'm having similar problems, and having problems finding any applicable solutions.

Comment: This is one of the trickiest issues with Erlang if you are processing lots of binary data. Recon will point you to processes that leak references, you can also compile with bin_opt_info which may give you some hints. I aggressively hibernate processes that deal with lots of binaries, and am careful to binary:copy() 32 byte or more data. In my instance much of the problem as inserting small chunks of a larger binary into record or map structures, this didn't allow for the larger binary to be cleared out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`erlang:process_info/2` call](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#process_info-2) with a second argument of `binary` might help, but in general you should have a look at the [Recon library](http://ferd.github.io/recon/), as I believe it can help you with this. Its author, Fred Hébert, posted a [highly useful article about using it](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/11/7/logplex-down-the-rabbit-hole) in his blog.